# Case insensitive search jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, find

Please help me with a question.

There is html with this structure (simplified):

```
<div id="data">
   <div description="Andy">
      <div class="ig"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></div>
      <div>Andy</div>
   </div>
   <div description="Cramly">
      <div class="ig"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></div>
      <div>Crasly</div>
   </div>
   <div description="Sam">
      <div class="ig"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></div>
      <div>Sam</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And there is a search text field with the id "find".
The task is to ensure that when you enter in this field, only  will remain whose part matches the entered one.
I made this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#find').change(function(){
        var filter = $(this).val();
        if (filter) {
            $matches = $('#data').find(':Contains(' + $('#find')[0].value + ')');
            $('div[description]','#data').not($matches).hide();
            $matches.slideDown();
        } else {
            $('#data').find('div').show();
        } return false;
        })
        .keyup( function () {
            $(this).change();
        });
</script>
```

It works but is case sensitive.
I just can’t make the search case-insensitive.
How can I change the code? Or maybe use some other method?